# How to handle MySQL too much tables trouble?

Tags: mysql, database, resources

I'm building application where users can import their applications. For every application that user import he has option to import his users. Also, he has ability to add custom fields to the table where his users are stored. When I proposed solution that creates a new table for every users application, my chief told me that's not good solution because there will be too much tables (for 1000 applications 2000 tables). Now I'm wondering what is the optimal solution to this MySQL resource trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You have a single core users table with the most common fields (id, username, password, email, application id, etc.), where the application id distinguishes between users of different applications.

You create a property definition table, where you have application id, property id and property name fields as a minimum (if other tables are extendible as well, then you should have a field identifiying the table the property relates to).

You will also need a properties table to hold the actual propery values. If multiple tables are extendable, then you may consider having multiple properties table. The properties table will have application id, user id, property id, property value fields as a minimum. Property value field should have a general data type, such as varchar because you can store almost all data types as text.

This way you can avoid creating separate user table for each of the applications. The drawback is that it will be more complicated to retrieve and edit user data.